# Failed to find the class io.confluent.connect.gcs.GcsSinkConnector while starting kafka-gcs confluent connector

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-storage, ubuntu-16.04, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using confluent connector for kafka and Google Cloud Storage(GCS). I installed confluent using:

(I am doing this on Ubuntu 16.04 and all these commands were executed in the home directory.)

```
curl https://packages.confluent.io/archive/5.0/confluent-5.0.0-2.11.tar.gz | tar xz
```

I then installed confluent-hub by:

```
curl http://client.hub.confluent.io/confluent-hub-client-latest.tar.gz | tar xz
```

I then installed the kafka-GCS connector using:

```
confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-gcs:5.0.1
```

I then export the path using:

```
export PATH=<insert-path-here>/confluent-5.0.0/bin:$PATH
```

I then start confluent using:

```
confluent start
```

it shows:

```
This CLI is intended for development only, not for production
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.pc9RaNNQ
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
kafka is [UP]
Starting schema-registry
schema-registry is [UP]
Starting kafka-rest
kafka-rest is [UP]
Starting connect
connect is [UP]
Starting ksql-server
ksql-server is [UP]
Starting control-center
control-center is [UP]
```

Checking confluent by:

```
confluent status
```

gives me:

```
This CLI is intended for development only, not for production
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

control-center is [UP]
ksql-server is [UP]
connect is [UP]
kafka-rest is [UP]
schema-registry is [UP]
kafka is [UP]
zookeeper is [UP]
```

All is fine up until now. Zookeeper and kafka are both up and running. Now when I use the following command to start the kafka-gcs confluent connector:

```
confluent load gcs -d quickstart-gcs.properties
```

it gives the following error:

```
Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name 
matches io.confluent.connect.gcs.GcsSinkConnector
```

The quickstart-gcs.properties file is in the home directory and looks something like this:

```
name=gcs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.gcs.GcsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=test

gcs.bucket.name=test_bucket
gcs.part.size=5242880
flush.size=3

gcs.credentials.path=/path/to/kafka/key.json

storage.class=io.confluent.connect.gcs.storage.GcsStorage
format.class=io.confluent.connect.gcs.format.avro.AvroFormat
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner
                  .DefaultPartitioner

schema.compatibility=NONE

confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
confluent.topic.replication.factor=1

confluent.license=
```

The line:

```
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner
                  .DefaultPartitioner
```

actually reads:

```
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
```

I had to write it like that because of the editor limitations. Sorry for that.

The last line in quickstart-gcs.properties as per the [documentations](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-gcs/index.html#connect-gcs) actually reads:

```
confluent.license=""
```

but it did not work for me.

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** As per @cricket_007 comment:

```
curl http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins
```

gives:

> [{"class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.0.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.0.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.tools.SchemaSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"2.0.0-cp1"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.0.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.0.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.0.0"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.tools.SchemaSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"2.0.0-cp1"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"2.0.0-cp1"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"2.0.0-cp1"}]

Comment: Please show the output of `curl http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins`

Comment: In your Kafka Connect worker config, what's `plugin.path` set to? Does the GCS connector JAR appear in any of the paths for that config item?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added the output in the question description as EDIT 1

Comment: As per that output, it doesn't look like Kafka Connect has loaded the GCS Connector. Note: I do not think `confluent start` is meant to work with `confluent-hub`

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, that is the problem. I have followed all the steps given in the documentation. Any solution to load GCS in kafka connect  would be of great help.

Comment: I would first check that the `plugin.path` directory does have the GCS connector. Then, I would suggest starting Kafka Connect with the file that contains that property using `connect-standalone` or `connect-distributed`. In other words, try not using `confluent start` or `confluent load`